# spring data mongodb _id mapping preference

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data mongodb framework in my java application to persist my application data in mongodb. In my java model class I have two fields.

1) A field objId with @Id annotation on it.
2) A field id

with respect to mapping to _id key in the mongodb document saved, which one will get preference or will I get an error for multiple mapping. I am using spring data mongo 1.6.1. I know I could have tested this out but I do not have local environment setup.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is in documentation http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.7.0.M1/reference/html/

> MongoDB requires that you have an '_id' field for all documents. If
>   you don’t provide one the driver will assign a ObjectId with a
>   generated value. When using the MongoMappingConverter there are
>   certain rules that govern how properties from the Java class is mapped
>   to this '_id' field.
>
> The following outlines what property will be mapped to the '_id'
>   document field:
>
> A property or field annotated with @Id
>   (org.springframework.data.annotation.Id) will be mapped to the '_id'
>   field.
>
> A property or field without an annotation but named id will be mapped
>   to the '_id' field.

As you can see @Id (objId) will take precedence.

Comment: So I have a field id in one of my pojo (without @Id annotation)... What do I do, sothat spring won't consider it to be "_id"... i.e. Is there any "NotId" annotation (I want this annotation over my id field in pojo)?

Answer (score 8):

you can use @Field("id") to disable map id field to _id

Comment: This is a working solution