# Deserialized document from mongo missing one field. Using Spring Data Mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, serialization

I have a Mongo collection that has documents that look like the following.  In reality there are many other fields, but alternateIds is unique in its structure and is a problem.

```
{
    "_id": 99999,
    "alternateIds": {
        "id": [{
            "id": "999",
            "idSpace": "SPACE1"
        }]
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Data Mongo to get the document into a POJO as follows.

```
MongoOperations mongoOperations = mongoInstance.getMongoOperations("myMongoDb");

MongoMyDocument myDocument = mongoOperations.findOne(
    new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(Long.parseLong(idUnderTest))),
    MongoMyDocument.class, "myMongoCollection"
);
```

The classes for receiving the document as are follows.  Again, the actual POJO has many other fields, but all the other fields are getting populated fine, so I've excluded them for the sake of simplicity.

```
public class MongoMyDocument {
    private Long id;
    private MongoAlternateIdSegment alternateIds;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public MongoAlternateIdSegment getAlternateIds() {
        return alternateIds;
    }
    public void setAlternateIds(MongoAlternateIdSegment alternateIds) {
        this.alternateIds = alternateIds;
    }
}

public class MongoAlternateIdSegment {
    private List<MongoIdSegment> id;

    public List<MongoIdSegment> getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(List<MongoIdSegment> id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class MongoIdSegment {
    private String id;
    private String idSpace;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getIdSpace() {
        return idSpace;
    }
    public void setIdSpace(String idSpace) {
        this.idSpace = idSpace;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, the myDocument object gets populated properly with all the values from the mongo document, except for field alternateIds.  This field is null.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here.  Using 1.10.9 RELEASE for the Spring Data Mongo version.

Comment: Maybe Mike L is onto something. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387335/spring-data-mongodb-id-mapping-preference) makes me think you should try using an annotation in the POJO.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like this might actually be a defect with the Spring Data Mongo package.  I did an experiment where I get the document as a String, then deserialize that to my target object using GSON and it works fine.  The alternateIds field is populated.  For example:

```
String jsonDocument = mongoOperations.findOne(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(testId)), String.class, "myMongoCollection");

Gson gson = new Gson();
MongoMyDocument myDocument = gson.fromJson(jsonDocument, MongoMyDocument.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the property name “id”, try it with other names.
As default, Mongo POJOS idProperty convert id as _id.
Also, there is a bug on it, "[Pojo codec conversion missing id field](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-2750)"