# PropertyReferenceException: No property _id found for type Entity

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using spring boot and mongodb for my project. I faced a problem with a property **_id** in my repository class. Before executing this query which is generated by my repositoryImpl class, I executed generated query in mongodb and it works fine.

If you change **_id** to **id** in java code, the *PropertyReferenceException* will disappear but the query stops working properly. It means that the underscore is must be presented here.

Can you help me, pls?

**Intellij idea console log:**

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property _id found for type Payment! Did you mean 'paid','id'?
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReference(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:83)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.InheritingExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.resolveExposedField(InheritingExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:59)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:94)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.getReference(ExposedFieldsAggregationOperationContext.java:71)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:392)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperationRenderer.toDBObject(AggregationOperationRenderer.java:56)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:580)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1570)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1499)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1488)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.repository.PaymentRepositoryImpl.findAllTaxpayerIds(PaymentRepositoryImpl.java:137)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:479)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.findAllTaxpayerIds(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy149.findAllTaxpayerIds(Unknown Source)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.service.CashFlowService.parse(CashFlowService.java:238)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.service.CashFlowService.read(CashFlowService.java:197)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.service.CashFlowService.save(CashFlowService.java:127)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.service.CashFlowService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3fca468f.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.service.CashFlowService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$97e0b255.save(<generated>)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.web.rest.CashFlowResource.upload(CashFlowResource.java:158)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.web.rest.CashFlowResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3bcfdc83.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.aop.logging.LoggingAspect.logAround(LoggingAspect.java:85)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:48)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.TimedMethodInterceptor.invoke(TimedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
at com.ryantenney.metrics.spring.AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.invoke(AbstractMetricMethodInterceptor.java:59)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.web.rest.CashFlowResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$edd4ccb1.upload(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
at com.codahale.metrics.servlet.AbstractInstrumentedFilter.doFilter(AbstractInstrumentedFilter.java:111)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at com.hazelcast.web.WebFilter.doFilter(WebFilter.java:373)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:155)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at com.uzbekinvest.hayot.security.jwt.JWTFilter.doFilter(JWTFilter.java:36)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
```

**Payment Class**

```
package com.uzbekinvest.hayot.domain;

    import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
    import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Field;

    import javax.validation.constraints.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.time.LocalDate;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Objects;
    import java.util.Set;

    /**
     * A Payment.
     */

@Document(collection = "payment")

    public class Payment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @DecimalMin(value = "0")
    @Field("amount")
    private double amount;

    @NotNull
    @Field("start_date")
    private LocalDate startDate;

    @NotNull
    @Field("end_date")
    private LocalDate endDate;

    @Field("loan")
    private Loan loan;

    @Field("policy")
    private Policy policy;

    @Field("payment_details")
    private Set<PaymentDetail> paymentDetails = new HashSet<>();

    @Field("paid")
    private double paid;

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-field - JHipster will add fields here, do not remove
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public Payment amount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
        return this;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public LocalDate getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public Payment startDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
        return this;
    }

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getEndDate() {
        return endDate;
    }

    public Payment endDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
        return this;
    }

    public Loan getLoan() {
        return loan;
    }

    public void setLoan(Loan loan) {
        this.loan = loan;
    }

    public Policy getPolicy() {
        return policy;
    }

    public void setPolicy(Policy policy) {
        this.policy = policy;
    }

    public void setEndDate(LocalDate endDate) {
        this.endDate = endDate;
    }

    public double getPaid() {
        return paid;
    }

    public void addPayment(double paid) {
        this.paid += paid;
        this.amount -= paid;
    }

    public void setPaid(double paid) {
        this.paid = paid;
    }

    public Set<PaymentDetail> getPaymentDetails() {
        return paymentDetails;
    }

    public void setPaymentDetails(Set<PaymentDetail> paymentDetails) {
        this.paymentDetails = paymentDetails;
    }

    public void addPaymentDetail(PaymentDetail paymentDetail) {
        this.paymentDetails.add(paymentDetail);
    }

    // jhipster-needle-entity-add-getters-setters - JHipster will add getters and setters here, do not remove

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Payment payment = (Payment) o;
        if (payment.getId() == null || getId() == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return Objects.equals(getId(), payment.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hashCode(getId());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Payment{" +
            "id=" + getId() +
            ", amount='" + getAmount() + "'" +
            ", startDate='" + getStartDate() + "'" +
            ", endDate='" + getEndDate() + "'" +
            "}";
    }
}
```

**PaymentRepository class**

```
    package com.uzbekinvest.hayot.repository;

import com.uzbekinvest.hayot.domain.Payment;
import org.springframework.security.access.method.P;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Spring Data MongoDB repository for the Payment entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface PaymentRepository extends MongoRepository<Payment, String>, PaymentRepositoryCustom {

List<Payment> findByAmount(double amount);

List<Payment> findByStartDate(Instant startDate);

List<Payment> findByEndDate(Instant endDate);
}
```

**PaymentRepositoryImpl class**

```
package com.uzbekinvest.hayot.repository;

import ch.qos.logback.core.util.AggregationType;
import com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.Aggregations;
import com.hazelcast.util.StringUtil;
import com.mongodb.AggregationOptions;
import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.client.AggregateIterable;
import com.uzbekinvest.hayot.domain.Payment;
import com.uzbekinvest.hayot.domain.PaymentDetail;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.*;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.BasicQuery;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

public class PaymentRepositoryImpl implements PaymentRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Payment> findAllTaxpayerIds(String taxpayerId) {
        GroupOperation groupBy =
            group("_id")
                .first("amount").as("amount")
                .sum("paymentDetails.paid").as("totalPaid");

        MatchOperation taxpayerIdMatch = Aggregation.match(new Criteria()
            .orOperator(
                new Criteria("policy.organization.taxpayer_id").is(taxpayerId),
                new Criteria("policy.user.taxpayer_id").is(taxpayerId)
            ));
//        ProjectionOperation projection = project().andExpression("id");
//        SortOperation sortByStartDateAsc = sort(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "startDate"));

        Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            Payment.class,
            taxpayerIdMatch,
            unwind("paymentDetails"),
            groupBy,
//            project("id", "amount", "totalPaid"),
            new RedactAggregationOperation(
                new BasicDBObject(
                    "$redact",
                    new BasicDBObject(
                        "$cond", new BasicDBObject().append("if", new BasicDBObject(
                        "$gt", Arrays.asList("$amount", "$totalPaid")
                    ))
                        .append("then", "$$KEEP")
                        .append("else", "$$PRUNE")
                    )
                )

            )
        );

        AggregationResults<Payment> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
            (TypedAggregation<Payment>) aggregation, Payment.class
        );
        return aggregationResults.getMappedResults();
    }

    private Criteria createMatchCriteria(String name, String value) {
        return Criteria
            .where(name)
            .regex(Pattern.compile(value, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.UNICODE_CASE));
    }
}
```

**Mongodb query:**

```
{ "aggregate" : "__collection__" , "pipeline" : [ 
{ "$match" :  
{ "$or" : [ 
{ "policy.organization.taxpayer_id" : "201122919"} , 
{ "policy.user.taxpayer_id" : "201122919"}]}} , 
{ "$unwind" : "$paymentDetails"} , 
{ "$group" : { 
"_id" : "$_id" , 
"amount" : { "$first" : "$amount"} , 
"totalPaid" : { "$sum" : "$paymentDetails.paid"}
}} , 
{ "$redact" : 
{ "$cond" : { 
"if" : { 
"$gt" : [ "$amount" , "$totalPaid"]} , 
"then" : "$$KEEP" , 
"else" : "$$PRUNE"}
}
}
]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring data mongodb \_id mapping preference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387335/spring-data-mongodb-id-mapping-preference)